# Use d3.queue() to load .tsvs when working within Django

Tags: django, d3.js

I am trying to convert my old website to use Django. However, I don't know how to successfully load my data in d3 when working inside of Django frameworks.

I know the D3 visualization works because it renders it on the old website frameworks. It appears to just be an issue of how do I properly call the pathing for the data files.

I have tried various call methods to the files by making duplicate copies and placing them in different directories. But so far I can't figure out how to call the paths correct!

Here is the original set of code:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "../core/world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "worldData.tsv")
    .await(ready);
```

Here are two different method calls I have tried

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "{% static 'data/worldData.tsv' %}")
    .await(ready)
```

2 different errors occur:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/web_app/world_countries.json 404 (Not Found)

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/web_app/%7B%%20static%20'data/worldData.tsv'%20%%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it!

Change the pathing call to be: "/static/data/world_countries.json"

Code looks like this:

```
queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "/static/data/world_countries.json")
    .defer(d3.tsv, "/static/data/worldData.tsv")
    .await(ready);
```